# Parallel downloads with Multiprocessing and PySftp

Tags: python, download, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pysftp

I'm trying to create a code to download N files at the same type using pysftp and multiprocessing libs. I made a basic python training, got pieces of codes and combined them into one, but I can't get it work out. I'd appreciate if somebody helps me with that. The error occurs after the vFtp.close() command. In the part that suppose to start simultaneous downloads.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pysftp
import os

vHost='10.11.12.13'
vLogin='admin'
vPwd='pass1234'
vFtpPath='/export/home/'

os.chdir('d:/test/')
os.getcwd()

cnopts=pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

vFtp=pysftp.Connection(vHost,username=vLogin,password=vPwd,cnopts=cnopts)
vFtp.cwd(vFtpPath)
vObjectList=vFtp.listdir()
vFileList=[]
vFoldList=[]

for vObject in vObjectList:
    vType=str(vFtp.lstat(vObject))[:1]
    if vType!='d': 
        vFileList.append(vObject)
    else:   
        vFoldList.append(vObject)

vFtp.close()

def fDownload(vFileAux):
    vFtpAux=pysftp.Connection(vHost,username=vLogin,password=vPwd,cnopts=cnopts)
    vFtpAux.cwd(vFtpPath)
    vFtpAux.get(vFileAux,preserve_mtime=True)
    vFtpAux.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    vPool=Pool(3)
    vPool.map(fDownload,vFileList)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get the list of files then download them concurrently using multiple processes.

Instead of manually examining the files, try using the `walktree` method on the connection object: [pysftp walktree](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/cookbook.html#pysftp-connection-walktree)

Here is a working example I made in Python 3.5. I'm just using a local ftp server and small files, so I simulated a download delay. Change the `max_workers` argument to set the number of simultaneous downloads.

```
"""Demo using sftp to download files simultaneously."""
import pysftp
import os
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import time


def do_nothing(s):
    """
    Using this as the callback for directories and unknown items found
    using walktree.
    """
    pass


def download(file):
    """
    Simulates a 1-second download.
    """
    with pysftp.Connection(
            host='convox', username='abc', private_key='/home/abc/test') as sftp:

        time.sleep(1)
        print('Downloading {}'.format(file))
        sftp.get(file)


def get_list_of_files(remote_dir):
    """
    Walks remote directory tree and returns list of files.
    """
    with pysftp.Connection(
            host='convox', username='abc', private_key='/home/abc/test') as sftp:

        files = []

        # if this finds a file it will send the filename to the file callback
        # which in this case just appends to the 'files' list
        sftp.walktree(remote_dir, fcallback=files.append,
                      dcallback=do_nothing, ucallback=do_nothing)

    return files

if __name__ == '__main__':
    remote_dir = '/home/abc/remoteftp/'
    download_target = '/home/abc/localftp/'

    # if you don't specify a localpath in sftp.get then it just downloads to
    # the os cwd, so set it here
    os.chdir(download_target)

    files = get_list_of_files(remote_dir)
    pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
    pool.map(download, files)
```

edit: `ProcessPoolExecutor` is for running something on multiple cpu cores and will be limited by your processor. For network tasks like downloading you can use threads instead. In the above code this is only one change: instead of `ProcessPoolExecutor` import and use `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Then you can use more `max_workers`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very simple and clear example. I'll make some tests and let you know about the results.

Comment: Dears, I've another question still regarding this subject. How can I get a confirmation of the 'get', and print the successfully downloaded files? I'm having some difficulties to return the result of the function and print the result depending on it.